# Propositional logic formula of a special form.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am Dealing with a Proposition Logic Formula of a special form like this:

$($...$($$n$<sub>$1$</sub>$X$<sub>$1$</sub> $d$<sub>$1$</sub> $n$<sub>$2$</sub>$X$<sub>$2$</sub>$)$ $d$<sub>$2$</sub> $n$<sub>$3$</sub>$X$<sub>$3$</sub>$)$ $d$<sub>$3$</sub> $n$<sub>$4$</sub>$X$<sub>$4$</sub>$)...)$ $d$<sub>$m$</sub>$n$<sub>$m+1$</sub>$X$<sub>$m+1$</sub>$)$

Here ,
($1$).$X$ is a propositional formula .The sub numbers indicate that they can be different.
($2$).$d$ can be an "$or$" or an "$and$" or "$implies$" or "$Double$ $implies$".The sub numbers indicate that they can be different.
($3$).$n$ can be $negation$ or $nothing$.The sub numbers indicate that they can be different.

Now , is there a **special name** for this kind of formula $?$ if there is ,What it is $?$

Comment: As far as I know, there is no name for a formula of this type. In fact, I'm not sure I fully understand why this kind of formula is special at all. At a glace, it seems like _every_ propositional formula is of this form (once you remove instances of abbreviations such as $\to$).

Comment: Not every formula is of this form.For example: **($A$ V $B$) V ($C$ V $D$)** is not of this form.Also, I mistakenly didn't include *Implies* and *double implies*. siqn for $d$.I am sorry for that.

Comment: I think I'd say it was left-normed.

Comment: Wait , what is the definition of left normed ? (I can't find it on the internet)